# What is this military turboprop aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, propeller-aircraft

I took a video of this military turboprop aircraft on August 6, 2020 at 7:03 PM in Long Beach, California. Here is a screenshot of it:
[image]

Comment: You should invest in a telescopic lens.

Answer (score 5):

From that really grainy, blurry picture, it looks like a C130 Hercules.

1. bulbous fuselage
2. Straight, ironing board-like wings
3. High wing configuration
4. 4 turboprop engines
5. Huge, high empennage
6. The rear is shaped like it could have a ramp.

If you are sure it was a turboprop, it looks like the C130 is a strong contender.

Comment: I agree that’s about the only thing it could be.  The C-130 doesn’t have a T-tail though.

Comment: @MichaelHall - My mistake. I must have been getting it mixed up with the turbofan C17 Globmaster.

Comment: It looks like a C-130 tail to me. You just can’t see the vertical stabilizer from below the horizontal stabilizer.

Comment: @MikeSowsun - It does look like the C130 tail. I remembered incorrectly whether the horizontal stabilizer was mounted directly on the tail or on the top of the vertical stabilizer. I spent time jumping out of both the 130 and the 17 too long ago to remember all of the details.